# How to extract only the last three parts of a string

Tags: regex

For the following bit of example code, I'm only interested in the last three bits separated by backslashes (e.g., Family/Genus/Species Name).

So for:

```
Magnoliopsida/Dilleniidae/Malvales/Malvaceae/Abutilon/Abutilon_theophrasti
Magnoliopsida/Rosidae/Euphorbiales/Euphorbiaceae/Acalypha/Acalypha_rhomboidea
Magnoliopsida/Rosidae/Sapindales/Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_negundo
Magnoliopsida/Rosidae/Sapindales/Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_nigrum
```

I want:

```
Malvaceae/Abutilon/Abutilon_theophrasti
Euphorbiaceae/Acalypha/Acalypha_rhomboidea
Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_negundo
Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_nigrum
```

How do I got about accomplishing this with regex?

Edit:
I'm using Notepad++'s Replace functionality with Regular expressions.
I'm able to "Find" what I want to replace with ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+[^/]/
But when I replace it with nothing, it does something weird. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: In what language? Different environments sometimes have their own regex syntax.

Comment: cannot you use split and reading backwards four times?

Comment: Why so set on regex? Split on `/` and take last 3. I suppose something like `[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$` would work though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard do not you think your regx should be backward cuz she wants the last 3 not the first 3 itmes?

Comment: @KickButtowski nope, `$` matches end of string.

Comment: Thats what the $ is for. It's the end of the line.

Comment: `$` matches end of string or end of line depending on a flag.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

> `(/(\w)*){3}$`

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a regex.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that involves strings.

If you're using PHP, then use the `explode` function to break the components into an array, and then use the last three elements of the array.

```
$name = 'Magnoliopsida/Dilleniidae/Malvales/Malvaceae/Abutilon/Abutilon_theophrasti';
$parts = explode( '/', $name );
$n = count($parts);
print $parts[$n-3] . ' ' . $parts[$n-2] . ' ' . $parts[$n-1];
```

Other languages will have similar functions.

Also `/` is a slash, not a backslash.  `\` is backslash.

Comment: she has not specified with what language?

Comment: Bingo. This will work if she happens to use PERL though.

Comment: I'm using the "Find what:/Replace with:" in Notepad++ for my text file. When I put "^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+[^/]/" as the "Find what" and "" as the "Replace with", it does something weird with the text.

Comment: does not work for me either. would you like to see other answer without using regex?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out...

I can search: `\n^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+[^/]/`
and replace with: `\n`

to get more-or-less what I want.

Thanks all!

Comment: Right, so you're removing the first 3 sections of each line. Cool. I don't think you need that last `[^/]` though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user specified Notepad++ as the application, I suggest replacing

```
^.+/(\w+/\w+/\w+)
```

with

```
$1
```

Comment: @KickButtowski: With proper quoting the regular expression will work in Java, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In Python

```
import re 
x="Magnoliopsida/Rosidae/Sapindales/Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_nigrum"
pattern=re.compile(r"\w+\/\w+\/\w+\/(\S+)")
y=pattern.match(x).groups()
print y
```

Output is ('Aceraceae/Acer/Acer_nigrum',)